# Reverse sort a column-based numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to sort (descending) a numpy array where the array is reshaped to one column structure. However, the following code seems not be working.

```
a = array([5,1,2,4,9,2]).reshape(-1, 1)
a_sorted = np.sort(a)[::-1]
print("a=",a)
print("a_sorted=",a_sorted)
```

Output is

```
a= [[5]
 [1]
 [2]
 [4]
 [9]
 [2]]
a_sorted= [[2]
 [9]
 [4]
 [2]
 [1]
 [5]]
```

That is due to the `reshape` function. If I remove that, the sort works fine. How can I fix that?

Comment: `np.sort(a, axis=0)[::-1]` should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need Axis should be 0 (Column wise sorting)

```
np.sort(a,axis=0)[::-1]
```

**Discussion:**

```
a = np.array([[4,1],[23,2]])
print(a)
Output:
[[ 4  1]
 [23  2]]


# Axis None (Sort as a flatten array)
print(np.sort(a,axis=None))
Output:
[ 1  2  4 23]


# Axis None (Sort as a row wise **(By default is set to 1)**)
print(np.sort(a,axis=1))
[[ 1  4]
 [ 2 23]]

# Axis None (Sort as a column wise)
print(np.sort(a,axis=0))
[[ 4  1]
 [23  2]]
```

For more details have a look in:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

Comment: This is the same as the comment on the question. At least make a reference.

Comment: I have added necessary info & reference. Thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As @tmdavison pointed out in the comments you forgot to use the `axis` option since by default np sorts matrices by row. By calling the reshape function, in fact, you're transforming the array into a 1-column matrix which sorting by row is trivially the matrix itself.
This would do the job

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5,1,2,4,9,2]).reshape(-1, 1)
a_sorted = np.sort(a, axis = 0)[::-1]
print("a=",a)
print("a_sorted=",a_sorted)
```

Extra points:

- [reference to the doc of sort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)
- Next time remember to make the code reproducible (no np before array and no imports in your example). This was an easy case but it's not always like this